# Intuition for $e^{i(px-Et)}$ rotating clockwise?

Tags: waves, conventions, oscillators, plane-wave

I can demonstrate it by example but it is very counterintuitive to me that the phase in $e^{i(px-Et)}$ rotates clockwise vs $e^{i(px+Et)}$ rotates counterclockwise as time increases.

Is there an intuition here for why $x$ and $t$ need opposite signs for the phase to move $x$-forward in time?

[image: img]

update added image:
[image: img]

Comment: It may be a matter of memorizing that multiplying by i is a counterclockwise phase shift

Comment: Ultimately the fact that multiplication by $i$ is a counterclockwise shift is a human convention. We could have chosen to define the complex plane so a multiplication by $i$ is a clockwise shift. So therefore I don't think there is any "intuition" possible for this, there's just a convention you have to remember.

Comment: You are right, a real number multiplied by i rotates counterclockwise, a convention of how we draw real and imaginary axes, so to add a forward phase in time we need an opposite sign

Comment: Update:Sin (and Cos) waves also need a minus sign in front of the time term to move forward.. consistent with Euler's identity referred to in the answer.

Comment: related:[any function f(x) is shifted to the right by f(x-1) and to the left by f(x+1)] https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/how-does-one-explain-that-transformations-inside-a-function-operate-in-the-opp

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with Eulers identity?

$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$

A decrease of theta, given the RHS corresponds to moving clockwise on the complex plane. Hence a negative sign decreases theta and thus rotates the complex clockwise

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with where is the zero crossing:

$$ y = m(x-x_0) $$

cross the x-axis at $x_0$, so if:

$$ x_0 = \omega t $$

increasing $t$ shifts things to the right (larger $x$).

And ofc, the phase is:

$$ \phi(x, t) = kx-\omega t$$

Comment: oh interesting, any function f(x) is shifted to the right by f(x-1) and to the left by f(x+1)